# In ViewPager, on sliding to 3rd tab, child fragment in tab1 disappears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 tabs in a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
I have a fragment for tab 1 which adds views to its 'linearlayout' container inside a relative layout dynamically.
i add dynamically some views in tab 1 fragment. I also added a complete fragment in that linearLayout container with other views up and down. this works fine.. every thing fine.

but when i go to 3rd page and come back. all views are there. but that complete fragment is vanished~~
**EDIT**
It vanishes from tab1 and appears below the views in tab2 where another childfragment is added..

First of all i have a listFragment in tab1 and tab2. based on listItem click i load a fragment in each tab, that both fragments in tab1 and 2 inflates the same below xml and adds dynamic views, but in some case i add a complete fragment instead of a view in the linear layout given in xml. 
**Problem** arose when i have to add two fragments in both new added fragments in tab 1 and tab2, after there were only lists, and slided to tab3. on returning back. fragment in 'tab1 main fragment' vanished and appeared below the fragment in 'tab2 main fragment'

this is the viewpager, in which i change different fragments by method setItem(fragment, position):

```
public static class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public static ArrayList<Fragment> tabs_fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>(
            3);

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
            ArrayList<Fragment> tabs) {
        super(fm);
        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.tabs_fragments = tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return tabs_fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs_fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if (tabs_fragments.contains(object)) {
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public static void setItem(Fragment fr, int position) {
        if (position <= 2 && position >= 0) {
            tabs_fragments.remove(position);
            tabs_fragments.add(position, fr);
        } else
            Log.d("adding tab", "wrong tab position to add fragment at");
    }
}
```

this is how i add my fragment to linearlayout where 'll' is the linear layout inside the relative layout, that is the actual contentview for the fragment on tab1

```
ll.addView(getTitle("Set Message Receive Settings"));
        // View smsRecLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_ev_sms_receive,
        // container, false);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("id", eventId);
        b.putInt("event", eventTypeId);
        Fragment fr = new FrEv_SMSReceive();
        fr.setArguments(b);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(ll.getId(), fr, "fr_sms_receive").commit();
```

this is the layout of fragment where another fragment is added in linear layout 'fr_event_container'.
FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EventDetails" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/fr_event_container_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sep1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_event_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/sep1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/addOther"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/addOther"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addOther"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
    android:text="Next"
    android:width="90dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to know that the problem was in using the same layout for both tabs without changing its Id at runtime by `setId`;

Although the fragments were in different tabs but Android was treating the layout that was first added as main, so if I added a fragment in tab2 after tab1 then any thing added in tab2 or tab2 version of that layout was going in tab1(first added).

I changed layoutIds at runtime and problem is solved.

Answer (score 11):

The ViewPager has a maximum offscreen page limit. 
You can set it higher with `setOffscreenPageLimit(int)`

Comment: Actually i have noticed that when go to tab3, that fragment from tab1 comes and be added to under the views in tab2. where same copy of relativeLayout is being used as is in tab1.
is there something wrong in this copying of same layout for both tabs?
i am inflating above given layout for both tabs.

Comment: Sorry I have to admit not to have read your whole code and assumed you forgot this common pitfall. Maybe you can post some more of your code, since we do not actually see your viewpager etc. Also im not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, with adding fragments into your layout.

Comment: by the way your solution also works. but i can't understand what is the problem.
thanks. but i can't upvote my reputation is lower than 15 :-/

Comment: ok i upload more code for the solution of problem for others.

Comment: ViewPager automatically destroys Fragments(/tabs)that are not actually in sight to save memory and such. With setOffscreenPageLimit you can set this limit high. If you set this to 2, that means you can always have 3 (1 visible, 2 off screen) without the ViewPager destroying them, and re-creating whenever you scroll back to them. If the problem is that after re-creation (so when not using setOffscreenPageLimit) your fragments are messed up, then your re-adding/re-creation is messed up ;)

Comment: thank you now they are in place and not messing with each other with offscreenlimit to 2. but do you know why that fragment was coming in tab2 after hiding from tab1 :-O

Comment: Like I said, your code probably messes up the re-creation somewhere. It is fixed now, because your fragments just get added once and are not destroyed when they're offscreen. 
Good luck and feel free to accept the answer, it will get you more answers in the future if you have a proper acceptance percentage :)

Comment: ohhh thanks a lot for advice + good answer. I will also be in touch and i accept your answer now :)
actually i am new and just 20 :P but so much in love with programming.
i will upvote your answer as soon as i get reputation of 15.